# Injecting into a non-SQL site (PHP only)

Tags: php, code-injection

I've got a CMS site without SQL. Everything is written into the files.

However there is a function (`login($login, $pass)`) that checks POST data from the login form with a simple if-else statement

```
if 
    login-data-from-file == POST['login'] 
and
    password-data-from-file == POST['pass'] 
then 
   "Log user in"
```

I wonder if there is a way to inject into such code. What do you think?

Comment: I think it's bad idea to store all data in files...

Comment: It's true, but the code is not mine. It was the first time I've found such case and I was that surprised that decided to write about it here.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't, because presumably you are just comparing strings.

However, immunity to SQL injection does not automatically make any app secure. There is always [cross site scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) and [session fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) to worry about (just two of the most common attack vectors among many others).

Answer (score 1):

You can not inject directly into PHP code if you are not using eval or any other black magic. Although having user and password stored in plain text in a file is not very safe. If you still want to do that you should make sure that

1. The file containing username and password is stored in location outside publicly accessible folder
2. The password is hashed and salted (very important!)
3. there are no places in code where user would be able to access the file containing username and password

Comment: Absolutely, the file with such data is safe and cannot be read from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to inject into this code, if you made correct if-else statements. It's possible to send `NULL` value (%00), but it shouldn't change anything.

Comment: Doesn't %00 sound rather like empty string?

Comment: Yeah, but why can't I just type into login/password form strong like this: 5 OR 1==1.
Then PHP uses if-else statement and I'm in, right?

Comment: No, because 5 OR 1==1 it's a string for PHP. You can type for ex. Login = 5 OR 1==1 and no password at all and if...else statement will be false, because string '5 OR 1==1' != string from file and password is also incorrect.